# Acts_as_taggable gem. Cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of categories. When you click on a category lets say Computers it should only show a tag cloud of the items in that category in this case Computers. Tags from the Mobile Phone category should not be showing.

Currently my tag cloud shows all tags across all categories.

Im using the Acts_as_tagable_gem https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

**How would someone go about showing only the tags inside that category?**

Here is my view. **Please refer to tag_cloud**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class = "col-md-3">
    <h1>
      <strong><%= @category.name %></strong>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9">
    <div id="tag_cloud">
      <% tag_cloud Item.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name, id: @category.id), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
            <div class="box panel panel-default">
              <div class="itemlisttitle"><%= item.title %></div>    
            <%= link_to image_tag(item.image.url (:medium)), item %>
              <div class ="panel-body">
              <div class = "itemlistprice">$<%= item.price %></div>
              <div class = "itemlistretailer"><%= image_tag item.user.avatar(:thumb) %> Retailer: <%= link_to item.user.username, item.user %></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes **Please refer to the last line**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :categories

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :users
  get 'user_items'  => 'users#show_user_items'
  root 'items#home'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'show'  => 'users#show'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :items
  get 'items_new' => 'items#new'


  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'categories#show', as: :tag
```

Category Controller **Please refer to show action**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category,   only: [:show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :index, :edit]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end

end
```

Comment: what does `Item.tag_counts` do? Please post the code for that method

Comment: @Kenobi i added a link to the gem.